# GUI's in Python

Tags: python

The way I have it right now, I'm working with Easygui, but I don't really like how Easygui looks on my Windows 7 system. I was wondering if there is any way to use the actual Windows GUI's (WinAPI, is it called?)

If this is possible, where can I find a tutorial on how to use it? (Ex putting in different buttons than just "Ok", and that kind of thing

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For direct access to the windows api you can use [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) (there are 64bit version available, the 32 is just part of the name).

```
import win32api

win32api.MessageBox (None, "Hello, World!", "Greetings")
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without downloading stuff? Just curious

Comment: Nope, the only gui built into python that I am aware of is [Tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter).

Comment: @user2152304: There's [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html), but it's rather low-level.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make actual good looking application for Windows I would probably recommend that you look into using [QT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29) bindings, and I think the best alternatives available today are [PythonQt](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/) or [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide).